# Geometric intuition to $X^{T}n + b = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing a [Data Science for Engineers course on NPTEL](https://onlinecourses.nptel.ac.in/noc21_cs23/preview) and I came across the concept of hyperplane for the first time. A lecture states that:

> The hyperplane is described by an equation as follows $$X^Tn + b = 0$$

Unfortunately, no explanation was given by the instructor on the geometric intuition behind this equation.

I understand that if $X$ is a vector on the hyperplane and $n$ is a perpendicular to it, then $X^Tn$ should be equal to zero. I don't get what's $b$ doing in the equation. A bit of googling revealed that it is supposed to the "offset from origin". I am unable to visualize that in the context of the equation.

It would be great if you could take the pain of drawing some kind of visualization and explain the geometric origin/intuition behind this equation using that.

Comment: Fix $\eta \in \mathbb R^n$. Then $H = \{x: x^T \eta = 0\}$ is a hyper-plane passing through the origin. Define $f: H \to \mathbb R$ by $f: x\mapsto x^T \eta$. Then, put $g \equiv f+b$ so that the graph of $g$ is exactly what your equation describes.

Comment: Didn't understand the last two statements :( Would be helpful if you could elaborate with less notations, and actually derive the equation.

Comment: Yes, sorry, what I wrote is actually wrong... The hyperplane is the zero set of $g$ in my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^Tn =0  \}$ is a hyperplane through the origin perpendicular to $n$ (I think you agree with this and so I take it as a starting point). Then if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the set
$$\{ x + \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^Tn =0  \} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: (x-\alpha)^Tn =0  \} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^Tn-\alpha^Tn =0  \}$$
is the same hyperplane but shifted so that it goes through $\alpha$. The expression on the right is of the form $x^Tn + b=0$ with $b=-\alpha^Tn$. It follows that every hyperplane can be expressed in the form you mention.

Conversely, to see that a set of the form $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^Tn+b =0  \}$ is a hyperplane, choose any vector $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^Tn \neq 0$ (there are many, try to check this!). Then
$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x^Tn+b =0  \}=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: (x+\frac{b}{\alpha^Tn}\alpha)^Tn =0  \}$$ is a set of the form above (look at the middle term in the first display) and so it is a hyperplane through $-\frac{b}{\alpha^Tn}\alpha$ normal to $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer. I confused myself by having the wrong picture for $X$ in my mind. I was imagining it as a vector that's *on* the plane, in the sense that if $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are two vectors on the plane, I was thinking of $X$ as being $\vec{a}-\vec{b}$. Rather, $X$ is one of those $\vec{a}$ or $\vec{b}$.

Comment: @Aniruddha right, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It may help to think about this in 3 dimensions first for a good geometric interpretation. Here's a very nice post on the subject: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/eqnsofplanes.aspx

To summarize, one way to geometrically define a plane is to pick a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and a normal vector $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and define the plane as all points $(x,y,z)$ such that the vector $\langle x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0 \rangle$ is orthogonal to the normal vector $\langle a,b,c \rangle$. In other words, all points $(x,y,z)$ such that $\langle a,b,c \rangle \cdot \langle x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0 \rangle = 0 $, which can be rewritten as

$$ a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c(z-z_0) = 0 .$$

This is often rewritten as

$$ ax + by + cz = d $$

where $d = a x_0 + b y_0 + c z_0 $.

Note that means we could have also written this equations as

$$ a(x-\frac{d}{a}) + by + cz = 0.$$

In other words, a plane passing through point $(\frac{d}{a},0,0)$ with normal vector  $\langle a,b,c \rangle$.

Now onto the hyperplane generalization. The idea is very similar: consider a $k$ dimensional hyperplane $x_1 n_1 + \cdots + x_k n_k + b = 0$. We could write this as

$$ n_1(x_1 - (-\frac{b}{n_1})) + n_2 x_2 + \cdots + n_k x_k = 0$$

So the hyperplane is intersecting point $(-\frac{b}{n_1},0,\cdots,0) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ with nornal vector $\langle n_1,\cdots n_k \rangle$. Similarly, you could interpret it as intersecting point $(0,-\frac{b}{n_2},\cdots,0) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ with nornal vector $\langle n_1,\cdots n_k \rangle$ (or any other point on the plane).

"offset from the origin" simply means the for any nonzero $b$, the hyperplane does not pass through the origin (which can be easily seen by plugging in $X = 0$ into your hyperplane equation).